# How to Fix “Ensure text remains visible during webfont load bootstrap-icons.woff” Error in PageSpeed

Tags: font-face, webfonts, google-fonts

Ensure text remains visible during webfont load issue is not getting resolved in google pagespeed insights report even after adding **font-display: swap** to the CSS.

```
@font-face {
    font-display: swap;
    font-family: 'bootstrap-icons';
    src: url('../fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preload` and `font-display: swap;` are used together then this problem is solved

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet preload" as="style" />

@font-face {
    font-display: swap;
    font-family: 'bootstrap-icons';
    src: url('../fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```